# \usechemmodule from chemmacros undefined

Tags: chemmacros

I'm trying to use the thermodynamics module, among others, to display enthalpy but it doesn't seem to work.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{all}

\begin{document} 
  \enthalpy*(r){1} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on the *doesn't seem to work* part? Right now, there are issues on MikTeX, reports have already been made.

Comment: If `\usechemmodule` is undefined then you have an outdated version and you should just leave it away. If you get errors about modules not loaded then I suspect you're using MiKTeX: there are known issues which should be fixed soon (https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2403/). Meanwhile you can use `\usepackage[compatibility=4.7]{chemmacros}`, leave `\usechemmodule` away, and work with the older version. (Beware that then the command was called `\Enthalpy`)

Comment: (The older manual is available here: https://github.com/cgnieder/chemmacros/releases/tag/v4.7)

Comment: Sorry for the jumble. I'm using sharelatex.com but I also tried running it on MacTeX. The first message I got was that \enthalpy was undefined. When I added \usechemmodule{all}, it said \usechemmodule was undefined as well.

Comment: I erased \usechemmodule{all} and used \Enthalpy instead of \enthalpy and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: I suppose that sharelatex is still shipping an older version of `chemmacros`. I'm not sure about their update policies, but in general web-LaTeX services aren't the fastest, I seem to have gathered.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work both with versions prior to v5.0 and current versions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

% versions below 5.0 don't have the macro. Let's provide it
% to expand to the “false” branch if it isn't defined:
\providecommand\IfChemCompatibilityTF[4]{#4}

% let's check if the current version of chemmacros (or rather the
% compatibility mode it is used with) is 5.0 or newer:
\IfChemCompatibilityTF{>=}{5.0}{
  % load all the modules we need. “all” is overkill but will do:
  \usechemmodule{all}
}{
  % in the new versions \Enthalpy is called \enthalpy. Let's
  % take care we can use the same command either way:
  \let\enthalpy\Enthalpy
}

\begin{document} 

\enthalpy*(r){1} 

\end{document}
```