# Chemmacros: Environments reaction and experimental undefined

Tags: environments, chemistry, chemmacros

I get the following errors and have no idea, why. I just updated all my packages. I am using MikTeX 2.9 on Windows 7 and TeXmaker 4.3.
Just spent like an hour searching for an answer and didn't get any.
Would be very good if anyone could help me.
The \ch{} command, however, works.

> ! LaTeX Error: Environment reaction undefined.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \begin{reaction}
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Environment experimental undefined.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \begin{experimental}
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. \data
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. \NMR

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}    %SI units
\usepackage{chemmacros} %formula, spectra, ...

\begin{document}
\ch{CH4}

\begin{reaction}
A -> B
\end{reaction}

\begin{experimental}
\data*{yield} \SI{555}{\milli\gram} ugly, brown whatever
\NMR{1,H}(250)[CDCl3] \val{9.99} (m, \#{5})
\end{experimental}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There have been some major changes to [`chemmacros`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chemmacros/chemmacros_en.pdf) with version 5.0 and now features a modular structure. You can either run in backwards compatibility mode via `\usepackage[compatibility=4.7]{chemmacros}` or you load `\usepackage{chemmacros}` and then the required modules for your environments, namely `\chemsetup{modules={reactions,spectroscopy}}`. The `reaction` environment needs the `reactions` module, `experimental` needs the `spectroscopy` module.

Comment: If you can't be bothered to check which modules you need you can simply load them all via `\chemsetup{modules={all}}`.

Comment: What @moewe said

Comment: Out of curiosity: I thought I made the changes quite noticeable in the `chemmacros` manual and yet you didn't find them after an hour of searching. Should I rework the manual?

Comment: Thanks a lot @moeve :) \chemsetup{modules={all}} worked.
Funny thing is that i could compile a similar file this friday, 09.10. on my other computer, just by using \usepackage{chemmacros} in the praeambula, without loading any modules. When i wanted to compile the very same file on my laptop, i got the errrors.
Since it worked on my desktop computer, i thought it's not about the code and just googled for people having the same issue.

Comment: @Wulfram When you plan using the same file on different computers with one having the older version installed you should definitely go for the `\usepackage[compatibility=4.7]{chemmacros}` version instead of loading modules (and definitely not *all* of them…). Better yet: make sure you have the same up to date versions on both machines, check the manual for the changes made and choose only the modules you need.

Comment: @Wulfram Might be interesting for you if you deal with different versions of `chemmacros`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271415

Comment: @moewe would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @clemens Done. Feel free to comment.

Answer (score 4):

There have been [some major changes to `chemmacros` with version 5.0](http://www.mychemistry.eu/2015/10/chemmacros-v5/). The package now features a more modular structure.

You can either run in backwards compatibility mode via

```
\usepackage[compatibility=4.7]{chemmacros}
```

---

Or you load `\usepackage{chemmacros}` (which loads the new modular structure if you version is >= 5.0) and then the required modules for your environments, namely

```
\chemsetup{modules={reactions,spectroscopy}}
```

The `reaction` environment needs the `reactions` module, `experimental` needs the `spectroscopy` module.

If you can't be bothered to check which modules you need you can simply load them all via

```
\chemsetup{modules={all}}
```

Refer to the [`chemmacros` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chemmacros/chemmacros_en.pdf) for more details and a list of modules.